# Error booting Linux. Root and swap does not exist

Tags: linux, boot

I imported a VM with Oracle Linux 7.5 into XenServer but when I boot the linux the following error appears:

```
dracut-initqueue[296]: Warning: Could not boot.
dracut-initqueue[296]: Warning: /dev/ol/root does not exist
dracut-initqueue[296]: Warning: /dev/ol/swap does not exist

Warning: /dev/mapper/ol-root does not exist
Warning: /dev/ol/root does not exist
Warning: /dev/ol/swap does not exist

Generating "/run/iniramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs

dracut:/#
```

I rebooted and went into rescue mode, then typed dracut -f, but it did not work

I need to recover the boot and I do not have the live cd. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely experiencing [this](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3326141).

Try running:

```
dracut --regenerate-all -f && grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

This will rebuild `initramfs` and solve naming issues in block devices (`/dev/sda1` might now be `/dev/xvde1` or something similar).

It has saved me when migrating to OracleVM from VMware.

More info on dracut [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dracut) and [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/dracut.8.html).

Comment: worked perfectly! I type this command booting in rescue mode. Thank you very much

Comment: if the rescue mode from hd does not work, mount a minimal image and use its rescue mode. drop to shell, chroot to your hd and apply the command above.

Comment: I also needed to add the xen block/net drivers.  This command worked for me (while migrating a physical machine's disk image to a Xen PV guest):  `dracut --regenerate-all --add-drivers "xen-blkfront xen-netfront" -f && grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: in emergency mode from centos 7 USB it doesnt have dracut, but is dracut user?
`dracut:/# dracut`
`sh: dracut: command not found`